# Google Analytics behaviour on sites that require log in

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website that require the visitor to log-in in order to visualize the content within. I widely searched GA FAQs searching something on the topic but I couldn't find anything.

How do I make sure that GA logs the activity correctly? Should I take any special measure like declaring custom variables or others in order to enhance the tracking performance?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics works by having the user's browser send information to a Google server using JavaScript you place on each page. It does not matter whether or not your site requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug indicated, as long as you have the tracking code on all the pages you want to track, you're good to go.

However, if you want to better understand the behavior of your members in and non-members in particular as separate segments (as it seems you are alluding to), then yes, you will need to use visit and/or visitor scope [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) and/or [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets) – I recommend going with the latter, i.e. using the newer [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en).

They're easy to set up and really make Google Analytics more enjoyable and meaningful.

For example you could create a custom dimension called 'User Type' that is set to Visitor level scope, meaning pan-session tracking that lasts as long as the GA cookie persists on the user's computer. Then just set the values to either Member or Non-Member and you're all set.

You might a bit of simple PHP to ascertain the login status and then feed the dimension value into the tracking code, something sort of like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) { ?>
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Logged In');
} else {
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Not Logged In');";
}
<? } ?>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545357/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-in-php) for more on that.